# QGIS "Controlled by atlas/Fixed scale" makes random scale for features

Tags: qgis-2, atlas

I have a point layer as control point in an atlas. I set map to be controlled by atlas, and there's only one option for point layer: fixed scale.

[image]

I render it, and every feature gets it's own scale, some of which are completely useless.

Is there a way to fix this thing?

QGIS version 2.18.19

Feature 1:

[image]

Feature 2: far away, barely usable

[image]

Feature 3: USELESS!!!

[image]

Every time same features get the same scale. These three are in the same city, impossible that WGS/Google projection has different scale there within 30 km.

What is going on?!

**addition:** Just to try, I added a field "sc" and pasted the correct scale there, and set scale in atlas to be used from this field. Did not help at all.

**addition 2:** just tried moving the map a little bit in composer, and scale changes by several times!

[image]
[image]

Comment: I found here a changeset but how resolve issue i don't know
https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/commit/007e237f7ae4e492eab6420234d42c0e96c57a54

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found out the reason: the project by default has no ellipsoid set, hence wrong sizes/distances.

Here's where you can fix it: set ellipsoid to `WGS 84` (the one with a space).

[image]

Comment: Hmm this did not help in my case. Still only "fixed scale" is available (QGIS 3.10)

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem like this:
In the composer select map layer. Under Main properties you can select Scale. Click on the icon on the right side and select Edit. Just tipe in the wanted scale.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I was having this same problem and was *extremely* frustrated. I eventually figured out that the problem was that I was using a layer of dissolved points -- but the "margin around feature" setting only works for features that are polygons. In my case, I ran a buffer around the points I wanted to guide the atlas, then dissolved those buffered features into individual features.